# Ubuntu froze, then after poweroff it will not start⠀⠀⠀⠀

Tags: boot, freeze

Yesterday I was playing a game on my laptop, and by mistake I opened a webpage and my laptop froze. I shut it down from the button, and when I try to turn on the laptop it stops at this purple screen with five orange and white dots.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First, try to boot with a liveUSB or LiveCD to discard any hardware malfunction. If the system on the live media boot and you can access your disk, go to /var/log/boot.log and check for any problem or error. You can also check the other log files and look for more errors.

If the live image does not boot, remove it, and reboot your computer, then, when the Ubuntu logo appear, press the ESC key until you see the boot log (pressing the ESC key 2 times is enough)

Take note of the errors and post it here